# Arima with xreg, rebuilding the fitted values by hand

Tags: r, time-series, arima, excel

I'm using R to do some time series estimation.  I'm trying to rebuild the fitted values from an Arima model by hand to use in an Excel spreadsheet using the estimated coefficients and the input data. I can use the fitted command, but I'm trying to understand more how it works. Ex:

```
library(MASS)
library(tseries)
library(forecast)

set.seed(1)
N = ts(mvrnorm(50, mu=c(0,0), Sigma=matrix(c(1,0.56,0.56,1), ncol=2), 
       empirical=TRUE), frequency=12)
head(N)

>            [,1]       [,2]
>[1,] -0.05270976  0.7239571
>[2,] -0.67232349 -0.6631604
>[3,] -0.20193415  0.8176053
>[4,] -0.54278281 -2.0458285
>[5,]  1.38279994  0.9405811
>[6,]  1.39979731  2.1717733

# Model: x(t) = a * x(t-1) + e(t)
fit = Arima(N[,1], order=c(1,0,0), include.constant=FALSE)

> fit  
>Series: N[, 1]  
>ARIMA(1,0,0) with zero mean          
>
>Coefficients:  
>         ar1  
>       0.0293
>s.e.   0.1400  
>
>sigma^2 estimated as 0.9791:  log likelihood=-70.42
>AIC=144.84   AICc=145.1   BIC=148.66

# Build the fitted values: x(t)=a * x(t-1) 
pred  = fit$coef[1] * lag(fit$x, -1) 
pred1 = fitted(fit)
head(cbind(pred, pred1))   

>             pred         pred1
>[1,]           NA -2.255567e-05
>[2,] -0.001541849 -1.541849e-03
>[3,] -0.019666597 -1.966660e-02
>[4,] -0.005906915 -5.906915e-03
>[5,] -0.015877313 -1.587731e-02
>[6,]  0.040449232  4.044923e-02
```

In this case, `pred` and `pred1` match.

However when I add in an `xreg`:

```
# Model: x(t) = a*x(t-1) + b*xreg + e(t)
fit1 = Arima(N[,1], order=c(1,0,0), xreg=N[,2], include.constant=FALSE)

>fit  
>Series: N[, 1]  
>ARIMA(1,0,0) with zero mean         
>
>Coefficients:  
>         ar1  N[, 5]  
>       0.0860  0.5606  
>s.e.   0.1401  0.1155  
>
>sigma^2 estimated as 0.6675:  log likelihood=-60.85
>AIC=127.69   AICc=128.22   BIC=133.4

# Build the fitted values: x(t) = a*x(t-1) + b*xreg 
pred2  = fit1$coef[1]*lag(fit1$x, -1) + fit1$coef[2]*fit1$xreg 
pred21 = fitted(fit1) 
head(cbind(pred2, pred21))

>              pred2     pred21
>[1,]         NA  0.4041670
>[2,]  0.4013329 -0.4112205
>[3,] -0.4296032  0.4325201
>[4,]  0.4410005 -1.2037229
>[5,] -1.1936161  0.5792684
>[6,]  0.6462336  1.2911169
```

In this case, `pred2` and `pred21` do not match, and the only thing changed was adding an `xreg`. The only time I cannot build out the fitted values by hand is when the AR part is included. I was able to do it when only MA parts were included with the `xreg`.  I would really appreciate knowing how `Arima` treats `xreg` when generating the fitted values.

Comment: This sounds like a programming question rather than a statistics question per se. Are you just asking how the function is working? What language are you using, R?

Comment: I'm using R, I will add that to the post. More so I need to know how the function is working so I can rebuild the model by hand rather than using the fitted() command.

Comment: If you just want to see the code for the function, type the function name at the command prompt. I'm still not sure whether this is about understanding how ARIMA works (in which case, it belongs here) or understanding how the code works (in which case, it probably belongs on [Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/)).  However, it will need a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269/1217536); can you add one?

Comment: I want to know why the fitted values I'm building do not match the fitted values produced by the fitted() command.  I will try to add the data set and code.

Comment: I wasn't sure how to add the data set, so I just rewrote my post with a reproducible example. Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks for doing that. Unfortunately, I don't know enough about time-series etc to help w/ this, but there are experts here. For now we can leave your Q here, but others w/ a clearer view of the issues may recommend migrating it to SO, if appropriate (the idea would just be to get you to where you can best be helped).

Answer (score 9):

You have misunderstood the model. It is not
$$ y_t = ay_{t-1} + bx_t + e_t$$
as you assume. Rather it is
\begin{align}
y_t & = bx_t + n_t \\
n_t &= a n_{t-1} + e_t.
\end{align}
This is explained in the help file for `arima`:

> If an `xreg` term is included, a linear regression (with a constant term
>   if `include.mean` is true and there is no differencing) is fitted with
>   an ARMA model for the error term.

There is further discussion  comparing these two models on my blog at http://robjhyndman.com/hyndsight/arimax/.

Note: You appear to be using the `forecast` package, although this is not loaded in your code.

Comment: Thanks, Mr. Hyndman. I was able to find the solution to my problem and posted the solution above.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you, Prof. Hyndman, for the answer. Thank you, ajhubb, for posting your solution based on Prof. Hyndman's comments. I'm working through manually rebuilding the values by hand as well.

*(My apologies for posting this as an answer, but I don't have enough reputation to comment on your answer.)*

When I ran the relevant snippet of code in [ajhubb's answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/110589/arima-with-xreg-rebuilding-the-fitted-values-by-hand/110790#110790), I got the following error:

`Error in '+.default'(n_fit, f$coef[3] * f$xreg) : non-conformable arrays`

It was caused by `n_fit` being a 49-element `ts` object, while `f$xreg` is a 50x1 `matrix` object. Here is the corrected snippet of code I ran:

```
 library(MASS)
 library(forecast)

 set.seed(1)
 N <- ts(mvrnorm(50, mu = c(0,0), Sigma = matrix(c(1,0.56,0.56,1), ncol = 2), empirical = TRUE), frequency = 12)
 f <- Arima(N[,1], order = c(2,0,0), xreg = N[,2], include.constant = FALSE) # Fits a linear regression with AR(2) error structure
 n <- f$x - f$coef[3] * f$xreg # Errors from linear regression component
 n_l1 <- lag(n, -1)
 n_l2 <- lag(n, -2)
 n_fit <- (f$coef[1] * n_l1) + (f$coef[2] * n_l2) 
 pred <-  n_fit[c(1:48)] + (f$coef[3] * f$xreg)[c(3:50)] # n_fit elements 1:48 are t=3,...,50; this matches f$xreg elements 3:50
 pred # View manually fitted values
 fitted(f)[c(3:50)] # View fitted values from f object
 round(pred, 14) == round(fitted(f)[c(3:50)], 14)
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Mr. Hyndman, here is the solution

```
    f = Arima(N[,1], order=c(2,0,0), xreg=N[,2], include.constant=FALSE)
    n=f$x-f$coef[3]*f$xreg #finds the AR error part of the model
    n_l1=lag(n,-1)
    n_l2=lag(n,-2)
    n_fit=n_l1*f$coef[1]+f$coef[2]*n_l2 #finds the fitted AR errors
    pred=n_fit+f$coef[3]*f$xreg #Gives correct fitted values
```

Comment: Although implementation is often mixed with substantive content in questions,
we are supposed to be a site for providing information about statistics, machine
learning, etc., not code. It can be good to provide code as well, but please
elaborate your substantive answer in text for people who don't read this language
well enough to recognize & extract the answer from the code.