# Interpretation of coefficients from dynamic model with ARIMA errors

Tags: time-series, forecasting, arima

I am reviewing the advanced section of the otext book on forecasting (https://www.otexts.org/fpp/9/1) and am hoping to obtain a clarification. Example 9.1 aims to model consumption based on income. Both series shown are quarterly % changes in US consumption, e.g. (Q3-Q2)/Q2 %, both are stationary. The parameter estimate for the fit2 model (copied from the otext to below) shows that income 2 quarters ago is related to consumption in the current period. The point estimate for the parameter is 0.242. **So, what is the correct interpretation of this parameter in this specific case?**

Model output (from link above):

```
> (fit2 <- Arima(usconsumption[,1], xreg=usconsumption[,2], order=c(1,0,2)))
Series: usconsumption[, 1] 
ARIMA(1,0,2) with non-zero mean 

Coefficients:
         ar1      ma1     ma2  intercept  usconsumption[, 2]
      0.6516  -0.5440  0.2187     0.5750              0.2420
s.e.  0.1468   0.1576  0.0790     0.0951              0.0513

sigma^2 estimated as 0.3396:  log likelihood=-144.27
AIC=300.54   AICc=301.08   BIC=319.14
```

My own interpretation is that a 1% increase in the percentage change in income (in absolute terms, not multiplicatively) is associated with a 0.24% increase in the percentage change consumption (again in absolute terms) two quarters later. So, for example when the % change in income goes from 1 to 2 % (say between Q4 and Q1) then we expect the % change in consumption to increase by 0.24% two quarters later (in Q3).

**Is my interpretation correct?** 
Note - While this topic has been raised before (e.g. [Interpretation of regression with ARIMA(0,1,1) error](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/278888/interpretation-of-regression-with-arima0-1-1-error)) I am yet to find a succinct and satisfying answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, that's correct. The only change I'd make is to include "on average". Here is how we describe the same problem in the upcoming 2nd edition of our book:

> The slope coefficient shows that a one unit increase in $x$ (a 1% increase in personal disposable income) results on average in 0.24 units increase in $ y$  (an average 0.24% increase in personal consumption expenditure).

As you have recognized, this example is a little tricky to describe because the two variables are percentage changes.